# function in foreach or foreach in function

Tags: php, function, foreach, output, constants

Is there a performance difference between the following two ways? Which one is better when printing a lot of constants?

```
function printLang($lang){
    return 'var ' . $lang . ' = "' . CONSTANT($lang) . '";' . PHP_EOL;
}

foreach($langVars as $l) {
    echo printLang($l);
}
```

and

```
function printLang($lang)
{
    foreach($lang as $l) {
        echo 'var ' . $l . ' = "' . CONSTANT($l) . '";' . PHP_EOL;
    }
}

printLang($lang);
```

Comment: second one should run only once and then return.

Comment: A function call is always more expensive than a loop (in PHP).

Comment: This is why php included yield keyword ;)

Comment: Do you really need to print a lot of constants? Faster should be the second one but you can measure that.

Comment: second one is faster but wrong; `echo 'var ' . $ll . ' = "' . CONSTANT($l) . '";' . PHP_EOL;` should be `echo 'var ' . $l . ' = "' . CONSTANT($l) . '";' . PHP_EOL;`. The speed difference is to little to notice.

Comment: If your code uses a database or reads from/writes to files or uses an external service then the access to constants doesn't matter. Whichever way you choose, the improvement (if any) is too small to make any difference.

Comment: Round about ~500 Constants. So the second way is better, thanks